# PECL extension installation on XAMPP (Windows)

Tags: php, xampp, pecl, id3, id3v2

I need some help please, have tried but am not even close to thinking about winning.

I need to get the [ID3 PECL](https://pecl.php.net/package/id3) running on XAMPP(v7.4.5) for Windows.

I have spent the day yesterday trying to work through the [PECL articles](https://www.php.net/manual/en/install.pecl.php) on the PHP.net website and it unfortunately does not make much sense to me, as my knowledge is not on that level yet. I have also tried looking for a dll file for the ID3 extension, but cannot find any. Only the source files are available for download for the ID3 PECL page.

Is there perhaps someone with enough patience who can explain the process in more layman's terms... dumb it down for me as it were?

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**

***Can someone be of assistance?***

With the help of Lelio I now have a way to extract info from an MP3, I have added two lines to access the *Genre* as well as *Attached Picture* blocks. The *Genre* block works. The *Attached Picture* block however, does not.

Here is the updated code which is saved as a separate php file called *script-mp3-tag-reader.php*:

```
<?php
    function tagReader($file)
    {
        $id3v23 = array("TIT2","TALB","TPE1","TRCK","TDRC","TLEN","USLT","TCON","APIC");
        $id3v22 = array("TT2","TAL","TP1","TRK","TYE","TLE","ULT","TCO");
        $fsize = filesize($file);
        $fd = fopen($file,"r");
        $tag = fread($fd,$fsize);
        $tmp = "";
        fclose($fd);
        if (substr($tag,0,3) == "ID3")
        {
            $result['FileName'] = $file;
            $result['TAG'] = substr($tag,0,3);
            $result['Version'] = hexdec(bin2hex(substr($tag,3,1))).".".hexdec(bin2hex(substr($tag,4,1)));
        }
        if($result['Version'] == "4.0" || $result['Version'] == "3.0")
        {
            for ($i=0;$i<count($id3v23);$i++)
            {
                if (strpos($tag,$id3v23[$i].chr(0))!= FALSE)
                {
                    $pos = strpos($tag, $id3v23[$i].chr(0));
                    $len = hexdec(bin2hex(substr($tag,($pos+5),3)));
                    $data = substr($tag, $pos, 9+$len);
                    for ($a=0;$a<strlen($data);$a++)
                    {
                        $char = substr($data,$a,1);
                        if($char >= " " && $char <= "~")
                        {
                            $tmp.=$char;
                        }
                    }
                    if(substr($tmp,0,4) == "TIT2") $result['Title'] = substr($tmp,4);
                    if(substr($tmp,0,4) == "TALB") $result['Album'] = substr($tmp,4);
                    if(substr($tmp,0,4) == "TPE1") $result['Artist'] = substr($tmp,4);
                    if(substr($tmp,0,4) == "TRCK") $result['TrackNo'] = substr($tmp,4);
                    if(substr($tmp,0,4) == "TDRC") $result['Year'] = substr($tmp,4);
                    if(substr($tmp,0,4) == "TLEN") $result['Lenght'] = substr($tmp,4);
                    if(substr($tmp,0,4) == "USLT") $result['Lyric'] = substr($tmp,7);
                    if(substr($tmp,0,4) == "TCON") $result['Genre'] = substr($tmp,4);
                    if(substr($tmp,0,4) == "APIC") $result['AttachedPicture'] = substr($tmp,4);
                    $tmp = "";
                }
            }
        }
        if($result['Version'] == "2.0")
        {
            for ($i=0;$i<count($id3v22);$i++)
            {
                if (strpos($tag,$id3v22[$i].chr(0))!= FALSE)
                {
                    $pos = strpos($tag, $id3v22[$i].chr(0));
                    $len = hexdec(bin2hex(substr($tag,($pos+3),3)));
                    $data = substr($tag, $pos, 6+$len);
                    for ($a=0;$a<strlen($data);$a++)
                    {
                        $char = substr($data,$a,1);
                        if($char >= " " && $char <= "~")
                        {
                            $tmp.=$char;
                        }
                    }
                    if(substr($tmp,0,3) == "TT2") $result['Title'] = substr($tmp,3);
                    if(substr($tmp,0,3) == "TAL") $result['Album'] = substr($tmp,3);
                    if(substr($tmp,0,3) == "TP1") $result['Artist'] = substr($tmp,3);
                    if(substr($tmp,0,3) == "TRK") $result['TrackNo'] = substr($tmp,3);
                    if(substr($tmp,0,3) == "TYE") $result['Year'] = substr($tmp,3);
                    if(substr($tmp,0,3) == "TLE") $result['Lenght'] = substr($tmp,3);
                    if(substr($tmp,0,3) == "ULT") $result['Lyric'] = substr($tmp,6);
                    if(substr($tmp,0,3) == "TCO") $result['Genre'] = substr($tmp,3);
                    if(substr($tmp,0,3) == "PIC") $result['AttachedPicture'] = base64_encode(substr($tmp,3));
                    $tmp = "";
                }
            }
        }
        return $result;
    }
?>
```

In my *index.php* file I then load and use the above PHP script as follows:

```
<?php
    require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/script/php/script-mp3-tag-reader.php');
    $mp3 = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/media/audio/mp3/test_audio.mp3';
    $myResult = tagReader($mp3);
    print_r($myResult);
?>
```

When looking at `print_r($myresult);` one can see that the information is indeed there and correct... just not the Attached Image part. I seem to be extracting far more than is needed and do not know how to access only what I need.

Comment: @LelioFaieta, As stated as part of my question above, yes I have and cannot make much sense of it.

Comment: it is a perfectly clear guide, what is wrong with that?

Comment: btw, ID3, as stated in your link, is not maintained. Are you sure you want to install something that is updated last time 16 years ago? It probably will not be compatible with php 5 or 7

Comment: @LelioFaieta Clear, perhaps for you yes.

Comment: @LelioFaieta Do you have a suggestion for an alternative that may be useful?

Comment: What do you need it for?

Comment: I need to extract meta data such as Artist, Song, Genre, Year, etc from MP3 files and process said data that will ultimately be written to a spreadsheet.

Comment: So you neither have to rely on PECL's id3, nor on XAMPP 7? If you "only" want to get metadata out of MP3 files then please edit your question and remove "requirements" that you don't have at all. If you only need software in PHP visit http://getid3.sourceforge.net/

Comment: @AmigoJack If possible I would like to write meta data to MP3's as well.

Comment: Then I already answered everything.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick. It is not recently tested but should work to read the data you are looking for from a mp3 file.

```
function tagReader($file){
    $id3v23 = array("TIT2","TALB","TPE1","TRCK","TDRC","TLEN","USLT");
    $id3v22 = array("TT2","TAL","TP1","TRK","TYE","TLE","ULT");
    $fsize = filesize($file);
    $fd = fopen($file,"r");
    $tag = fread($fd,$fsize);
    $tmp = "";
    fclose($fd);
    if (substr($tag,0,3) == "ID3") {
        $result['FileName'] = $file;
        $result['TAG'] = substr($tag,0,3);
        $result['Version'] = hexdec(bin2hex(substr($tag,3,1))).".".hexdec(bin2hex(substr($tag,4,1)));
    }
    if($result['Version'] == "4.0" || $result['Version'] == "3.0"){
        for ($i=0;$i<count($id3v23);$i++){
            if (strpos($tag,$id3v23[$i].chr(0))!= FALSE){
                $pos = strpos($tag, $id3v23[$i].chr(0));
                $len = hexdec(bin2hex(substr($tag,($pos+5),3)));
                $data = substr($tag, $pos, 9+$len);
                for ($a=0;$a<strlen($data);$a++){
                    $char = substr($data,$a,1);
                    if($char >= " " && $char <= "~") $tmp.=$char;
                }
                if(substr($tmp,0,4) == "TIT2") $result['Title'] = substr($tmp,4);
                if(substr($tmp,0,4) == "TALB") $result['Album'] = substr($tmp,4);
                if(substr($tmp,0,4) == "TPE1") $result['Author'] = substr($tmp,4);
                if(substr($tmp,0,4) == "TRCK") $result['Track'] = substr($tmp,4);
                if(substr($tmp,0,4) == "TDRC") $result['Year'] = substr($tmp,4);
                if(substr($tmp,0,4) == "TLEN") $result['Lenght'] = substr($tmp,4);
                if(substr($tmp,0,4) == "USLT") $result['Lyric'] = substr($tmp,7);
                $tmp = "";
            }
        }
    }
    if($result['Version'] == "2.0"){
        for ($i=0;$i<count($id3v22);$i++){
            if (strpos($tag,$id3v22[$i].chr(0))!= FALSE){
                $pos = strpos($tag, $id3v22[$i].chr(0));
                $len = hexdec(bin2hex(substr($tag,($pos+3),3)));
                $data = substr($tag, $pos, 6+$len);
                for ($a=0;$a<strlen($data);$a++){
                    $char = substr($data,$a,1);
                    if($char >= " " && $char <= "~") $tmp.=$char;
                }
                if(substr($tmp,0,3) == "TT2") $result['Title'] = substr($tmp,3);
                if(substr($tmp,0,3) == "TAL") $result['Album'] = substr($tmp,3);
                if(substr($tmp,0,3) == "TP1") $result['Author'] = substr($tmp,3);
                if(substr($tmp,0,3) == "TRK") $result['Track'] = substr($tmp,3);
                if(substr($tmp,0,3) == "TYE") $result['Year'] = substr($tmp,3);
                if(substr($tmp,0,3) == "TLE") $result['Lenght'] = substr($tmp,3);
                if(substr($tmp,0,3) == "ULT") $result['Lyric'] = substr($tmp,6);
                $tmp = "";
            }
        }   
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, you are a life saver! This seem to work. Would you mind going through the trouble to break it down a bit, so that I may learn something?

Comment: Is there perhaps a way to extract the Attached Picture from the MP3 as well?

Comment: This code ignores various details of ID3v2 versions, such as different text encodings, desynchronization and compression. It is also no solution to OP's question, only an alternative. It will fail for big files.

Comment: @AmigoJack did you read the disclaimer at the beginning of my answer? Also if you have a better solution for OP’s question feel free to add it!

Comment: Yes: it missed all the details, just like the code misses lots of comments. Disclaimers are neither healers nor excuses.